# Single-Table DynamoDB Schema Design Tips

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I am taking a deep dive into NoSQL and the world of DynamoDB. After reading quite a few articles/literature and watching YouTube videos on it I am still quite confused on the approach to designing a single-table DynamoDB architecture and felt there's no better way than to throw myself into it with a personal project. I'm familiar with relational dbs but was hoping someone might be able to shed some light on the direction I should go.

I wanted to take a stab a practical solution of personal training, where a user signs up a business and as a result creates a user account that owns that business (ownership can be changed). This business can have locations, clients, workouts, etc.

Entities:

- Business

  - Will be uniquely identified by an `id`
  - A business has a set of settings
  - A business can have multiple locations.
  - A business can have many trainers and clients
  - A business can have many exercises, workouts, and programs
- Location

  - Will be uniquely identified by an `id`
  - A location has a set of settings
  - A location can belong to one business
  - A location can have many users
  - A location can have many clients
- Trainer

  - Will be uniquely identified by an `email`
  - A trainer can have many exercises, workouts, and programs
  - A trainer can have many clients
- Client

  - Will be uniquely identified by an `email`
  - A client can have many exercises, workouts, and programs
  - A client can have many trainers
- Exercise

  - Will be uniquely identified by an `id`
  - A exercise can belong to many workouts and programs
  - A exercise can have many clients and trainers
  - A exercise can have many locations
- Workout

  - Will be uniquely identified by an `id`
  - A exercise can belong to many programs
  - A exercise can have many clients and trainers
  - A exercise can have many locations
- Program

  - Will be uniquely identified by an `id`
  - A exercise can have many clients and trainers
  - A exercise can have many locations

Access patterns:

- Get business

  - by id
- Get business settings

  - by id
- Get locations

  - by business `id`
- Get location

  - by location `id`
- Get location settings

  - by location `id`
- Get Trainers

  - by business `id`
  - by business `id` and location `id`
- Get Trainer

  - by trainer `id`
- Get Clients

  - by business `id`
  - by business `id` and location `id`
  - by business `id` and trainer `id`
- Get exercises

  - by business `id`
  - by business `id` and location `id`
  - by business `id` and trainer `id`
  - by exercise `id`
- Get workouts

  - by business `id`
  - by business `id` and location `id`
  - by business `id` and trainer `id`
  - by workouts `id`
- Get programs

  - by business `id`
  - by business `id` and location `id`
  - by business `id` and trainer `id`
  - by programs `id`

Entity Chart:

| Entity | PK | SK | GS1PK | GS1SK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BUSINESS | BUSINESS#id | BUSINESS#id |  |  |
| SETTINGS | BUSINESS#id | #SETTINGS |  |  |
| LOCATION | BUSINESS#id | LOCATION#id |  |  |
| SETTINGS | LOCATION#id | #SETTINGS |  |  |
| EXERCISE | EXERCISE#id | BUSINESS#id |  |  |
| WORKOUT | WORKOUT#id | BUSINESS#id |  |  |
| PROGRAM | PROGRAM#id | BUSINESS#id |  |  |
| USER | USER#id | USER#id | USER#email | USER#email |
| TRAINER | TRAINER#id | TRAINER#email | BUSINESS#id | TRAINER#id |
| CLIENT | CLIENT#id | CLIENT#email | BUSINESS#id | CLIENT#id |

Where I get stuck is deciding when to break data out.

- Each business will have multiple locations. Would **LOCATION** be another entity, or does that fall under **BUSINESS** (BUSINESS##LOCATION#)?
- Each location within a business will have its own settings. Would **SETTINGS** be another entity, or does that fall under **LOCATION** (LOCATION##SETTINGS)?

**USERS**

I'll be using NextAuth (or Auth.js) to handle frontend authentication and session storage. Next-Auth respects the single-table design pattern, however requires the USER to be set up according to their default USER schema in their [docs for their DynamoDB Adapter](https://authjs.dev/reference/adapter/dynamodb).

- Instead of separating **TRAINER** and **CLIENT** from **USER**. Would it be more appropriate to combine them to **USER** with an attribute of account type or something similar?

At what point do you decide that you need a GSI or LSI?

I'm not sure if im going down the right path with this particular schema design but am open to all suggestions! Thanks for all of your help in advanced!